# Strong convergence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have a sequence $(u_n)$ such that for a functional $I:W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^N)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $C^1-$classe we have $$I'(u_n)u_n=0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

and $$
\nabla u_n (x) \to \nabla u(x)~ \mbox{and} ~u_n(x) \to u(x) \mbox{a.e in} \mathbb{R}^N.
$$

We have also that $I'(u_n)\rightarrow 0$

How to deduce that 
$$I'(u_n)u\rightarrow 0~\text{and}~ I'(u) u=0$$

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any indications, why your claim should be true?

Comment: I found in in a paper https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Claudianor_Alves/publication/264957577_Existence_and_multiplicity_of_solution_for_a_class_of_quasilinear_equations/links/54d5e9a00cf25013d02c1e25.pdf

Comment: @gerw it is on page 77 case1

Comment: have you an idea @gerw ?

Comment: No. But the special structure of $I$ might be of some importance.